# $p(f|X,Y) \propto p(Y|X,f)p(f)$

Tags: probability, bayesian

I'm reading a paper where it mentions Gaussian processes, the author defines a prior distribution over function space $p(f)$ and states the following about the posterior $p(f|X,Y) \propto p(Y|X,f)p(f)$, where $X \in \mathbb{R^{N\times Q}}$ are the data inputs and $Y \in \mathbb{R^{N \times D}}$ are the data outputs.

My question is, why is it correct to write $p(f|X,Y) \propto p(Y|X,f)p(f)$. In my viewpoint, from Bayes theorem one should have $p(f|X,Y) \propto p(Y,X|f)p(f)$ being correct, someone could help me understand the details behind it?